# Rounded corners Tkinter / Transparent image on Canvas Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm making a UI for an program. I managed to blur the window with a image in a label (see image), i wanted to round the edges of the window, so i created a png image with a corner [corner](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rUgRo.png) and i'm using ***self.window.wm_attributes('-transparentcolor','black')*** to make black of corner.png transparent.

but giving this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a2vo4.png)

the corner is on a canvas with this script

```
self.img = Image.open('corner.png')
self.canvas = Canvas(self.window, width=50, height=50,bd=0, highlightthickness=0, relief='ridge')
self.canvas.place(x=0,y=20)
self.photoimage = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.img)
self.canvas.create_image((0,0), image=self.photoimage,anchor='nw')
self.canvas.update()
```

I wanted to be able to remove this white background from the canvas, i already tried to place the blur and the corner on the same canvas, but every time the corner is placed the whole background turns white.

Edit: blur is only a screenshot png which updates every time the window is clicked, with opencv GaussianBlur.

Edit2: it's ***working***: [working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dZcM3.png)

Answer (score 0):

Update:
with this code i put together the corner with blur so not needing the canvas anymore
output: [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/luP2c.png)

```
import cv2 
from pathlib import Path
homeDir = str(Path.home())
path = homeDir + '\Desktop\blur.png'
path2 = homeDir + '\Desktop\corner.png'


from PIL import ImageTk, Image

background = Image.open(path)
foreground = Image.open(path2)

background.paste(foreground, (0, 0), foreground)
background.save(path)
```

Result on Edit2